# Homebrew is halfway installed. Can't re-install or uninstall - How can I manually uninstall?

Tags: terminal, command, installation, uninstallation, homebrew

I seem to have dug myself into a corner.

I was halfway through installing Homebrew the first time and it got stuck. After ~15 minutes of waiting I quit terminal. My original input was what's from the homebrew [homepage](https://brew.sh/).

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

I reopened terminal and tried to re-install and got -

```
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

So, as suggested, I ran

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

and got

```
-bash: brew: command not found
```

I tried to run the uninstall script from the Homebrew FAQ and that didn't seem to help either. Anything else I can try? How would I manually uninstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what happens now if you run ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)" again?

After you killed terminal did you ps auxw | grep -E 'ruby|curl' and kill those?

Are you using /usr/local for anything else? If not, you can rm -rf /usr/local and run the install command again.

Comment: First thing I did this morning was ran `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkl raw.gihub.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"` And it installed. I checked to make sure there was only one homebrew installed, and there is. I'm not sure what the issue was, but thank you @jrwren for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro at terminal but I found a line in my .gitconfig that prevented me from running the install:

```
[push]
    default = simple
```

After commenting that line out of my .gitconfig the install ran beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `rm -rf /usr/local` you might get permission denied or risk deleting files of other installed programs. Deleting only `/usr/local/Homebrew/` folder worked for me